# react-native link causes relinking (Android)

Tags: android, react-native

I recently encountered a problem I didn't have before...
Running `react-native link` causes code to be added to the android files that has already been added (tries to link dependencies that have already been linked. Any ideas why this would be happening?

```
"dependencies": {
      "lodash": "^4.17.4",
      "react": "16.2.0",
      "react-native": "0.52.3",
      "react-native-blur": "^3.2.2",
      "react-native-fabric": "^0.5.1",
      "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
      "react-native-firebase": "^3.3.1",
      "react-native-iap": "^0.2.17",
      "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.5.2",
      "react-native-mail": "^3.0.5",
      "react-native-onesignal": "^3.0.9",
      "react-native-sound": "^0.10.9",
      "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.6",
      "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.23",
      "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
      "redux": "^3.7.2",
      "redux-action-listeners": "^1.0.2",
      "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was due to wrong code in the file [`link.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/link/link.js) earlier, in this line.

`const isInstalled = linkConfig.isInstalled(project[platform], dependency.config[platform]);`

It is fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18207/files#diff-ca7cc59db13ac8eb27fe0a9a6c9debee) and the latest `link.js` also has the fixed code, replaced by this line

```
const isInstalled = linkConfig.isInstalled(project[platform], dependency.name, dependency.config[platform]);
```

Here's a link to the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18131)

Comment: Thank you Pritish! Do you know which version of react-native solves the issue?

Comment: According to their `git branches`, the latest `master branch` or `0.54-stable` and `0.55-stable` should fix it.

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by [Pritish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49571720/5102373) there was an issue in react-native calling `react-native link` links or re-links all android library meaning that it will call link script associated with your dependencies. A solution is to link only newly added library by calling `react-native link <LIBRARY_NAME>`.

For instance

If in your project you use [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) and [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) calling `react-native link` will link both `react-native-camera` and `react-native-fs`.

Now assuming you have already linked `react-native-camera` and you didn't add `react-native-fs`. After adding `react-native-fs` as a dependency if you want it to be linked (without relinking `react-native-camera`) call : `react-native link react-native-fs`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If command **react-native link** has been already hit before then all the dependancies will be added twice.

To avoid this always specific link library like this :
    **react-native link < Your Library Name >**

To remove duplicate dependancies remove duplicate entries from following files:
   1. build.gradle (Check dependancies)
   2. setting.gradle
   3. MainApplication.java (Check imports and getPackages())